# coverting WebMvcConfigurerAdapter to WebMvcConfigurer correctly

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I made a previous a login and registration with security layer project in 2017 using WebMvcConfigurerAdapter, however now this has been deprecated i'm struggling to update the code.

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

// Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static 
// resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources/ directory
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
}

//Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the 
// /WEB-INF/views directory
@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    viewResolver.setOrder(2);
    return viewResolver;
}
@Bean
public SimpleMappingExceptionResolver simpleMappingExceptionResolver()
{
    SimpleMappingExceptionResolver b = new SimpleMappingExceptionResolver();
    Properties mappings = new Properties();
    mappings.put("eMarket.controller.SpringException", "form/ExceptionPage");
    mappings.put("defaultErrorView", "form/error");
    b.setExceptionMappings(mappings);
    return b;
}
```

}

I tried using

```
@Configuration 
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer { ... }
```

When I do this the following errors occur:

```
- The type WebConfig must implement the inherited abstract method 
 WebMvcConfigurer.configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer)
- The type WebConfig must implement the inherited abstract method WebMvcConfigurer.getValidator()
- The type WebConfig must implement the inherited abstract method 
 WebMvcConfigurer.extendMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>>)
- The type WebConfig must implement the inherited abstract method 
 WebMvcConfigurer.addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry)
- The type WebConfig must implement the inherited abstract method 
 WebMvcConfigurer.addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver>)
- The type WebConfig must implement the inherited abstract method 
 WebMvcConfigurer.addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry)
- The type WebConfig must implement the inherited abstract method 
 WebMvcConfigurer.getMessageCodesResolver()
- The type WebConfig must implement the inherited abstract method 
 WebMvcConfigurer.configureHandlerExceptionResolvers(List<HandlerExceptionResolver>)
- The type WebConfig must implement the inherited abstract method 
 WebMvcConfigurer.configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer)
- The type WebConfig must implement the inherited abstract method 
 WebMvcConfigurer.configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer)
- The type WebConfig must implement the inherited abstract method 
 WebMvcConfigurer.addFormatters(FormatterRegistry)
- The type WebConfig must implement the inherited abstract method 
 WebMvcConfigurer.addReturnValueHandlers(List<HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler>)
- The type WebConfig must implement the inherited abstract method 
 WebMvcConfigurer.configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>>)
- The type WebConfig must implement the inherited abstract method 
 WebMvcConfigurer.configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry)
- The type WebConfig must implement the inherited abstract method 
 WebMvcConfigurer.configureAsyncSupport(AsyncSupportConfigurer)
- The type WebConfig must implement the inherited abstract method 
 WebMvcConfigurer.extendHandlerExceptionResolvers(List<HandlerExceptionResolver>)
- The type WebConfig must implement the inherited abstract method 
 WebMvcConfigurer.addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry)
```

Ideas on why would be appreciated

Comment: I’m not sure what you are asking. Why are you adding `@EnableWebMvc` as that isn’t on your original class. You should simple be able to use the `WebMvcConfigurer` as that now has `default` Methods in the interface. What doesn’t work that isn’t really clear from your question. \

Comment: Sorry the @EnableWebMvc was a typo. I have added the warnings that are provided when I use implements WebMvcConfigurer

Comment: This will only work if you use Spring 5 or higher, anything below that doesn't have the default methods. Also where do you get these warnings, your IDE or when actually compiling your code... Depending on your IDE that might not detect the default implementations from Spring.

Comment: Thank you, you've hit the nail on the head there. My version at home is Spring 5 but at my university is Spring 3.9. WebMvcConfigurerAdaptor still works on the university software.

Comment: I doubt it is 3.9 as there is no Spring 3.9 version :). But anything before 5 will give the error.